# draft.js : click on placeholder to start typing

Tags: draftjs

I have been trying to modify the way the draft.js placeholder works in my project.

Currently, if I click next to the placeholder, it will place the caret where I want it to be and the text will start typing as expected.
However if I click on the placeholder itself, it will select it as a normal text.
Instead, I would like the caret to appear when i click on the placeholder.

Maybe I didn't search hard enough but i haven't found any information on that topic so far.

```
        <Editor
          editorState={title}
          readOnly={!editMode || !editable}
          onChange={setTitle}
          handleKeyCommand={handleCommand}
          handleBeforeInput={handleCommand}
          handlePastedText={handleCommand}
          placeholder={formatMessage({ id: 'tickets.detail.newSubject' })}
        />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may need to include the css?

`import 'draft-js/dist/Draft.css';`

Comment: In my case this was the answer. It was placing the placeholder as plain text and without the gray text color, but white, so you couldn't differentiate between placeholder and real text. After adding the stylesheet I could see it as placeholder